# Add Purchase Order field to website checkout in Odoo 9 SaaS

Tags: odoo, saas, odoo-9, qweb

I need to add a PO field to the portal website checkout in Odoo 9 SA (SaaS version). I assume I should add a field in the qweb view through the "customize/HTML Editor" but I'm not sure how I can trigger saving of a field value client_order_ref field in the sale.order model when someone presses the "Pay now" button.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have found that you can enable an "Extra Info" step by going into the checkout part of the website and under "Customize" enable "Extra Step Option". However, I'm not sure the best way to modify the fields, specifically, how to have the content of the field in that step be associated with the right field (i.e. client_order_ref).

Anyone have any input on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the Extra Option is activated through the HTML Editor it is possible to edit the xml page named "Checkout Extra Info". According to [this documentation about Odoo E-Commerce Website](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/slides/slide/how-to-customize-your-e-commerce-website-224/pdf_content) only x_ field are accepted.